# My ALT+C button isn't working

Tags: animation, mesh, text-object

So I am in Blender 3.1 and I am trying to learn how to make a transformational text animation in Blender The creator of this text animation is from **tutor4u**.

This is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do0jF3zb5_U&list=PL6_z3o30LJDxmA24pwg2TvBo6vwqNl4TJ&index=6.

I am at the 2:21 mark and when I try to press **ALT+C**, the **Mesh from Curve\Meta\Surf\Text** just doesn't show up. I would some help on what to do.

[image: Sample]

Comment: That tutorial was done with a very old version of Blender (2.76) and the Alt-C hotkey was removed in version 2.8 by the look of it. Use the Object > Convert > Mesh menu route instead. You may well find other problems following a tutorial that old in a recent Blender version!

Comment: Or right click > Convert to > Mesh

Answer (score 0):

Forget the shortcut (Alt+C), and just do it manually - select the object (text) then Click *Object > Convert > Mesh* from the menu at the top of the viewport:

[image: Convert]